# Pull one column value from join statements based on column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my current query

```
SELECT O.SubStatus,
OM.ORDERID AS ReorderID, 
FROM [dbo].[Orders] O (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN OShipped OM (NOLOCK) ON O.OrderID = OM.POrderID
```

I want to Populate ReOrderID based on value of OM.PorderID or ROrderID. If OM.POrderID has a value, then populate it as ReOrderID and if ROrderID has value [which is from a Different table], then populate that value. These two columns in table MOrder and RPOrder are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Omitting the WITH keyword when using query hints is deprecated. The bigger concern is the liberal usage of NOLOCK. Are you ok with inaccurate results because sometimes rows will be returned twice and other times skipped? This is one of those other effects of using NOLOCK. It is not just dirty reads. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: As for your actual question, this is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where the columns are but this should work:

```
UPDATE OShipped      SET
    ReOrderID= coalesce(OM.POrderID,ROrderID ,0)
FROM
OShipped OM 
INNER JOIN
 [dbo].[Orders] O 
ON
 O.OrderID = OM.POrderID
```

Answer (score 0):

The main thing is the `COALESCE` function. In this example I'm pretending the "other table" you mention is named `OTHERTABLE` and that it's connected to your main order table on a column named `SomeKey`.

I'm also interpreting your question to mean (by "populate") that you want the value you're talking about to be reflected in the output of the `SELECT` statement, not that you want to modify actual tables in place. (If you want the latter, then Benjamin Moskovits's answer is more helpful.)

```
SELECT
 O.SubStatus,
 COALESCE(OM.ORDERID,OTHERTABLE.ROrderID) AS ReorderID, 
FROM [dbo].[Orders] O (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN OShipped OM (NOLOCK)
 ON O.OrderID = OM.POrderID
LEFT JOIN OTHERTABLE (NOLOCK)
 ON O.OrderID = OTHERTABLE.SomeKey
```